# Group by does not work - SQL 2008 R2

Tags: sql-server, group-by

I have 3 rows that I need to be outputted into just 1 row, the script below should do, but I can't seem to have the expected result, it always shows up as 3 rows, is there something I'm missing? should I sum all the fields since they are all in the "GROUP" clause?

Btw, its working just before I made changes to the following result fields;

```
TSL_DAY_A
TSL_NET_A
TSL_TX_SAL
TSL_CHG
```

These fields were initially assigned with 0.00 as default values.

I have my eyes already tired staring at it,...

```
SELECT BR_CODE
    ,N_CHECK
    ,CLAS_C
    ,CLAS_TRD_C
    ,STOR_NO
    ,SUM(TSL_NEW_A) AS TSL_NEW_A
    ,SUM(TSL_OLD_A) AS TSL_OLD_A
    ,SalesType
    ,SUM(TSL_DAY_A) AS TSL_DAY_A
    ,SUM(TSL_DIS_A) AS TSL_DIS_A
    ,TSL_DIS_B
    ,SUM(TSL_DIS_C) AS TSL_DIS_C
    ,TSL_DIS_D
    ,SUM(TSL_DIS_E) AS TSL_DIS_E
    ,TSL_Dis_F
    ,TSL_Dis_G
    ,TSL_Dis_H
    ,TSL_Dis_I
    ,TSL_Dis_J
    ,TSL_Dis_K
    ,TSL_Dis_L
    ,SUM(TSL_TAX_A) AS TSL_TAX_A
    ,TSL_TAX_B
    ,TSL_ADJ_A
    ,TSL_ADJ_POS
    ,TS_ADJ_NEG
    ,TSL_ADJ_NT_POS
    ,TSL_ADJ_NT_NEG
    ,SUM(TSL_NET_A) AS TSL_NET_A
    ,SUM(TSL_VOID) AS TSL_VOID
    ,SUM(TSL_RFND) AS TSL_RFND
    ,SUM(TSL_TX_SAL) AS TSL_TX_SAL
    ,SUM(TSL_NX_SAL) AS TSL_NX_SAL
    ,TSL_CHG
    ,SUM(TSL_CSH) AS TSL_CSH
    ,SUM(TSL_GC) AS TSL_GC
    ,TSL_EPS
    ,TSL_TND
    ,TSL_MCRD
    ,TSL_VISA
    ,TSL_AMEX
    ,TSL_DINERS
    ,TSL_JBC
    ,TSL_OTCRD
    ,TSL_SV_CHG
    ,TSL_OT_CHG
    ,SUM(TSL_FT) AS TSL_FT
    ,SUM(TSL_LT) AS TSL_LT
    ,SUM(TSL_NT) AS TSL_NT
    ,SUM(TSL_BEG_INV) AS TSL_BEG_INV
    ,SUM(TSL_END_INV) AS TSL_END_INV
    ,SUM(TSL_TC_CASH) AS TSL_TC_CASH
    ,SUM(TSL_TC_GC) AS TSL_TC_GC
    ,TSL_TC_EPS
    ,TSL_TC_TND
    ,TSL_TC_MCD
    ,TSL_TC_VIS
    ,TSL_TC_AMX
    ,TSL_TC_DIN
    ,TSL_TC_JBC
    ,TSL_TC_OC
    ,TSL_MCH
    ,TSL_SRL
    ,SUM(TSL_ZCNT) AS TSL_ZCNT
    ,TSL_TIME
    ,TSL_DTE
FROM(
    SELECT
        BR_CODE
        ,N_CHECK
        ,CLAS_C
        ,CLAS_TRD_C
        ,STOR_NO
        ,SUM(TSL_NEW_A) AS TSL_NEW_A
        ,SUM(TSL_OLD_A) AS TSL_OLD_A
        ,SalesType
        ,SUM(TSL_DAY_A) AS TSL_DAY_A
        ,SUM(TSL_DIS_A) AS TSL_DIS_A
        ,TSL_DIS_B
        ,SUM(TSL_DIS_C) AS TSL_DIS_C
        ,TSL_DIS_D
        ,SUM(TSL_DIS_E) AS TSL_DIS_E
        ,TSL_Dis_F
        ,TSL_Dis_G
        ,TSL_Dis_H
        ,TSL_Dis_I
        ,TSL_Dis_J
        ,TSL_Dis_K
        ,TSL_Dis_L
        ,SUM(TSL_TAX_A) AS TSL_TAX_A
        ,TSL_TAX_B
        ,TSL_ADJ_A
        ,TSL_ADJ_POS
        ,TS_ADJ_NEG
        ,TSL_ADJ_NT_POS
        ,TSL_ADJ_NT_NEG
        ,SUM(TSL_NET_A) AS TSL_NET_A
        ,SUM(TSL_VOID) AS TSL_VOID
        ,SUM(TSL_RFND) AS TSL_RFND
        ,SUM(TSL_TX_SAL) AS TSL_TX_SAL
        ,SUM(TSL_NX_SAL) AS TSL_NX_SAL
        ,TSL_CHG
        ,SUM(TSL_CSH) AS TSL_CSH
        ,SUM(TSL_GC) AS TSL_GC
        ,TSL_EPS
        ,TSL_TND
        ,TSL_MCRD
        ,TSL_VISA
        ,TSL_AMEX
        ,TSL_DINERS
        ,TSL_JBC
        ,TSL_OTCRD
        ,TSL_SV_CHG
        ,TSL_OT_CHG
        ,SUM(TSL_FT) AS TSL_FT
        ,SUM(TSL_LT) AS TSL_LT
        ,SUM(TSL_NT) AS TSL_NT
        ,SUM(TSL_BEG_INV) AS TSL_BEG_INV
        ,SUM(TSL_END_INV) AS TSL_END_INV
        ,SUM(TSL_TC_CASH) AS TSL_TC_CASH
        ,SUM(TSL_TC_GC) AS TSL_TC_GC
        ,TSL_TC_EPS
        ,TSL_TC_TND
        ,TSL_TC_MCD
        ,TSL_TC_VIS
        ,TSL_TC_AMX
        ,TSL_TC_DIN
        ,TSL_TC_JBC
        ,TSL_TC_OC
        ,TSL_MCH
        ,TSL_SRL
        ,SUM(TSL_ZCNT) AS TSL_ZCNT
        ,TSL_TIME
        ,TSL_DTE
    FROM
        (SELECT 
            @branchcode AS BR_CODE
            ,@ncheck AS N_CHECK
            ,@classc AS CLAS_C
            ,@classtrd AS CLAS_TRD_C
            ,@storeno AS STOR_NO
            ,SUM(CAST(NGTOTAL AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(OGTOTAL AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_NEW_A
            ,SUM(CAST(OGTOTAL AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_OLD_A
            ,@salestype AS SalesType
            ,SUM(((CAST(SALESREGULAR AS DECIMAL(16,2)) - CAST(SALESVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) +
                CAST(SALESCD20 AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALESCD5 AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALEPWD AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALESTGOVT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + 
                CAST(SALESZERORATED AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCREGULARAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCSCD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCSCD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCPWD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCPWD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(VOIDTRANAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(ITEMVOIDAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(TICKETRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(ITEMRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)))/1.12) + CAST(SALESVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) AS TSL_DAY_A --SUM(cast(round((cast(TSALES as decimal)/1.12),2) AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_DAY_A --Help
            ,SUM(ABS(CAST(DISCREGULARAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)))) AS TSL_DIS_A
            ,0.00 AS TSL_DIS_B
            ,SUM(CAST(DISCSCD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(DISCSCD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_DIS_C
            ,0.00 AS TSL_DIS_D
            ,SUM(CAST(DISCSCD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(DISCSCD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_DIS_E
            ,0.00 AS TSL_Dis_F
            ,0.00 AS TSL_Dis_G
            ,0.00 AS TSL_Dis_H
            ,0.00 AS TSL_Dis_I
            ,0.00 AS TSL_Dis_J
            ,0.00 AS TSL_Dis_K
            ,0.00 AS TSL_Dis_L
            ,SUM(CAST(VATSALEAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_TAX_A
            ,0.00 AS TSL_TAX_B
            ,0.00 TSL_ADJ_A
            ,0.00 AS TSL_ADJ_POS
            ,0.00 AS TS_ADJ_NEG
            ,0.00 AS TSL_ADJ_NT_POS
            ,0.00 AS TSL_ADJ_NT_NEG
            ,SUM(CAST(DGROSSSALES AS DECIMAL(16,2)) - CAST(TOTALTAXVALUE AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_NET_A --Help
            ,SUM(CAST(VOIDTRANAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_VOID
            ,SUM(ABS(CAST(ITEMRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)))) AS TSL_RFND
            ,SUM(((CAST(SALESREGULAR AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(SALESVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) +
                CAST(SALESCD20 AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALESCD5 AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALEPWD AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALESTGOVT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + 
                CAST(SALESZERORATED AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCREGULARAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCSCD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCSCD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCPWD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCPWD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(VOIDTRANAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(ITEMVOIDAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(TICKETRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(ITEMRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)))) AS TSL_TX_SAL --Help
            ,(CAST(SALESVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + (CAST(ZERORATEDSALEAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) - CAST(ZERORATEDSALETAXVALUE AS DECIMAL(16,2)))) AS TSL_NX_SAL
            ,SUM(CAST(CCARDATMCHRGONLINEAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_CHG --Help
            ,SUM(CAST(TENDERCASHAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_CSH
            ,SUM(CAST(OTHTENDERSMGCAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(OTHTENDERSODEXOAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_GC --+ CAST(TENDERCHKAMT AS DECIMAL) AS TSL_GC
            ,0.00 AS TSL_EPS
            ,0.00 AS TSL_TND
            ,0.00 AS TSL_MCRD
            ,0.00 AS TSL_VISA
            ,0.00 AS TSL_AMEX
            ,0.00 AS TSL_DINERS
            ,0.00 AS TSL_JBC
            ,0.00 AS TSL_OTCRD
            ,0.00 AS TSL_SV_CHG
            ,0.00 AS TSL_OT_CHG
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(BEGSI) AS INT)) AS TSL_FT
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(LASSI) AS INT)) AS TSL_LT
            ,SUM(CAST((CAST(QTYREGULAR AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYSCD20 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYSCD5 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYPWD AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYTGOVT AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYZERORATED AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
                + CAST(QTYVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(DISCREGULARQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(DISCSCD20QTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(DISCSCD5QTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(DISCPWD20QTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
                + CAST(DISCPWD5QTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(VOIDTRANQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(ITEMVOIDQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2))*-1 + CAST(TICKETRETQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2))*-1 + CAST(ITEMRETQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2))*-1 
                + CAST(ADDLOANTOTQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS INT)) AS TSL_NT
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(BEGSI) AS INT)) AS TSL_BEG_INV
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(LASSI) AS INT)) AS TSL_END_INV
            ,SUM(CAST(QTYREGULAR AS INT)) as TSL_TC_CASH
            ,SUM(CAST(OTHTENDERSMGCQTY AS INT) + CAST(OTHTENDERSODEXOQTY AS INT)) AS TSL_TC_GC --+ CAST(TENDERCHKQTY AS INT) AS TSL_TC_GC
            ,0 AS TSL_TC_EPS
            ,0 AS TSL_TC_TND
            ,0 AS TSL_TC_MCD
            ,0 AS TSL_TC_VIS
            ,0 AS TSL_TC_AMX
            ,0 AS TSL_TC_DIN
            ,0 AS TSL_TC_JBC
            ,0 AS TSL_TC_OC
            ,@machineno AS TSL_MCH
            ,0 AS TSL_SRL
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(ZCOUNTER) AS INT)) AS TSL_ZCNT
            --,LEFT(CONVERT(TIME,GETDATE()),8) AS TSL_TIME
            ,RIGHT('00'+RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(HH,GETDATE())AS VARCHAR(5))),2)+RIGHT('00'+RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(MI,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(5))),2)+RIGHT('00'+RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(SS,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(5))),2) AS TSL_TIME
            --,SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,WorkDate,111),6,2)+'/'+Right(convert(varchar,WorkDate,111),2)+'/'+left(convert(varchar,WorkDate,111),4) AS TSL_DTE
            ,SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,WorkDate,111),6,2)+Right(convert(varchar,WorkDate,111),2)+left(convert(varchar,WorkDate,111),4) AS TSL_DTE
        FROM dbo.TermZTran t
        LEFT JOIN
                (SELECT sLessee, sTenantNumber AS TenantCode, sStoreNumber FROM mLandlordStore) tInfo
            ON CAST(t.STORE AS INT) = CAST(tInfo.sStoreNumber AS INT)
        WHERE CAST(t.Store AS INT) = CAST(@branchcode AS INT) 
            --AND CAST(t.POS AS int) = CAST(@posno AS int)
            AND tInfo.sLessee = @lesseeCode
            AND CONVERT(nvarchar(10),t.WorkDate,101) = @trandate
            --AND CONVERT(nvarchar(10),t.WorkDate,101) = '04/16/2013' --@trandate
        GROUP BY 
            SALESVATEXEMPT
            ,ZERORATEDSALEAMT
            ,ZERORATEDSALETAXVALUE
            ,WorkDate
        ) tFinal
    --WHERE CAST(BR_CODE AS INT) = CAST('0040' AS INT)
    GROUP BY
        BR_CODE
        ,N_CHECK
        ,CLAS_C
        ,CLAS_TRD_C
        ,STOR_NO
        ,TSL_NEW_A
        ,TSL_OLD_A
        ,SalesType
        ,TSL_DAY_A
        ,TSL_DIS_A
        ,TSL_DIS_B
        ,TSL_DIS_C
        ,TSL_DIS_D
        ,TSL_DIS_E
        ,TSL_Dis_F
        ,TSL_Dis_G
        ,TSL_Dis_H
        ,TSL_Dis_I
        ,TSL_Dis_J
        ,TSL_Dis_K
        ,TSL_Dis_L
        ,TSL_TAX_A
        ,TSL_TAX_B
        ,TSL_ADJ_A
        ,TSL_ADJ_POS
        ,TS_ADJ_NEG
        ,TSL_ADJ_NT_POS
        ,TSL_ADJ_NT_NEG
        ,TSL_NET_A
        ,TSL_VOID
        ,TSL_RFND
        ,TSL_TX_SAL
        ,TSL_NX_SAL
        ,TSL_CHG
        ,TSL_CSH
        ,TSL_GC
        ,TSL_EPS
        ,TSL_TND
        ,TSL_MCRD
        ,TSL_VISA
        ,TSL_AMEX
        ,TSL_DINERS
        ,TSL_JBC
        ,TSL_OTCRD
        ,TSL_SV_CHG
        ,TSL_OT_CHG
        ,TSL_FT
        ,TSL_LT
        ,TSL_NT
        ,TSL_BEG_INV
        ,TSL_END_INV
        ,TSL_TC_CASH
        ,TSL_TC_GC
        ,TSL_TC_EPS
        ,TSL_TC_TND
        ,TSL_TC_MCD
        ,TSL_TC_VIS
        ,TSL_TC_AMX
        ,TSL_TC_DIN
        ,TSL_TC_JBC
        ,TSL_TC_OC
        ,TSL_MCH
        ,TSL_SRL
        ,TSL_ZCNT
        ,TSL_TIME
        ,TSL_DTE) dt
GROUP BY
    dt.BR_CODE
    ,dt.CLAS_C
    ,dt.CLAS_TRD_C
    ,dt.N_CHECK
    ,dt.STOR_NO
    ,dt.SalesType
    ,TSL_DAY_A
    ,TSL_DIS_A
    ,TSL_DIS_B
    ,TSL_DIS_C
    ,TSL_DIS_D
    ,TSL_DIS_E
    ,TSL_Dis_F
    ,TSL_Dis_G
    ,TSL_Dis_H
    ,TSL_Dis_I
    ,TSL_Dis_J
    ,TSL_Dis_K
    ,TSL_Dis_L
    ,TSL_TAX_A
    ,TSL_TAX_B
    ,TSL_ADJ_A
    ,TSL_ADJ_POS
    ,TS_ADJ_NEG
    ,TSL_ADJ_NT_POS
    ,TSL_ADJ_NT_NEG
    ,TSL_NET_A
    ,TSL_VOID
    ,TSL_RFND
    ,TSL_TX_SAL
    ,TSL_NX_SAL
    ,TSL_CHG
    ,TSL_CSH
    ,TSL_GC
    ,TSL_EPS
    ,TSL_TND
    ,TSL_MCRD
    ,TSL_VISA
    ,TSL_AMEX
    ,TSL_DINERS
    ,TSL_JBC
    ,TSL_OTCRD
    ,TSL_SV_CHG
    ,TSL_OT_CHG
    ,TSL_FT
    ,TSL_LT
    ,TSL_NT
    ,TSL_BEG_INV
    ,TSL_END_INV
    ,TSL_TC_CASH
    ,TSL_TC_GC
    ,TSL_TC_EPS
    ,TSL_TC_TND
    ,TSL_TC_MCD
    ,TSL_TC_VIS
    ,TSL_TC_AMX
    ,TSL_TC_DIN
    ,TSL_TC_JBC
    ,TSL_TC_OC
    ,TSL_MCH
    ,TSL_SRL
    ,TSL_ZCNT
    ,TSL_TIME
    ,TSL_DTE
```

Here's a script to create the sample tables and data

```
USE [LandLord]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[mLandlordStore]    Script Date: 04/25/2013 20:21:42 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[mLandlordStore](
    [IDNumber] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [sStoreNumber] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [sLessee] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [sLesseeNumber] [int] NOT NULL,
    [sHOGenerated] [varchar](1) NOT NULL,
    [LastTranNo] [int] NULL,
    [sSpace] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [sMallCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [sTenantNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [sClassCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [sTradeCode] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [sOutletNumber] [nvarchar](20) NULL,
    [nSaleType] [int] NULL,
    [BatchCount] [int] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
SET ANSI_PADDING OFF
GO
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ON
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (1, N'40', N'SMCOIN', 11002558, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'72', N'011002559', N'01', N'SAP', N'03', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (3, N'1033', N'SMCOIN', 103312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'73', N'7312345', N'01', N'SAP', N'04', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (4, N'1133', N'ACI', 113312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'74', N'7412345', N'01', N'SAP', N'05', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (5, N'1233', N'ALI', 123312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'75', N'7512345', N'01', N'SAP', N'06', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (6, N'1333', N'MWC', 133312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'76', N'7612345', N'01', N'SAP', N'07', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (7, N'1433', N'OCLP', 143312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'77', N'7712345', N'01', N'SAP', N'08', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (8, N'1533', N'RLC', 153312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'78', N'7812345', N'01', N'SAP', N'09', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (9, N'1633', N'SLE', 163312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'79', N'7912345', N'01', N'SAP', N'10', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (10, N'1733', N'STAR', 173312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'80', N'8012345', N'01', N'SAP', N'11', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (11, N'1833', N'WM', 183312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'81', N'8112345', N'01', N'SAP', N'12', 1, 0)
INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ([IDNumber], [sStoreNumber], [sLessee], [sLesseeNumber], [sHOGenerated], [LastTranNo], [sSpace], [sMallCode], [sTenantNumber], [sClassCode], [sTradeCode], [sOutletNumber], [nSaleType], [BatchCount]) VALUES (12, N'1933', N'FSI', 193312345, N'Y', 0, N'01', N'82', N'8212345', N'01', N'SAP', N'13', 1, 0)
SET IDENTITY_INSERT [dbo].[mLandlordStore] OFF
/****** Object:  Default [DF_mLandlordStore_LastTranNo]    Script Date: 04/25/2013 20:21:42 ******/
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[mLandlordStore] ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_mLandlordStore_LastTranNo]  DEFAULT ((1)) FOR [LastTranNo]
GO

USE [LandLord]
GO
/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[TermZTran]    Script Date: 04/25/2013 20:19:54 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[TermZTran](
    [HeaderID] [uniqueidentifier] NOT NULL,
    [WorkDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessDate] [smalldatetime] NOT NULL,
    [ProcessMode] [nvarchar](10) NOT NULL,
    [POSCount] [int] NULL,
    [SalePharma] [money] NULL,
    [SaleNonPharma] [money] NULL,
    [VoidAmount] [money] NULL,
    [VoidCount] [int] NULL,
    [ZCOUNTER] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [STORE] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [POS] [nvarchar](4000) NULL,
    [DATE] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TIME] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OGTOTAL] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [NGTOTAL] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [BEGSI] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [LASSI] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TSALES] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [QTYREGULAR] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [SALESREGULAR] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [QTYSCD20] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [SALESCD20] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [QTYSCD5] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [SALESCD5] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [QTYPWD] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [SALEPWD] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [QTYTGOVT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [SALESTGOVT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [QTYZERORATED] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [SALESZERORATED] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [QTYVATEXEMPT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [SALESVATEXEMPT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TDISCOUNT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCREGULARQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCREGULARAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCSCD20QTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCSCD20AMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCSCD5QTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCSCD5AMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCPWD20QTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCPWD20AMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCPWD5QTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DISCPWD5AMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DNETSALES] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [DGROSSSALES] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [SALESACCOUNTABILITY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [VOIDTRANQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [VOIDTRANAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [ITEMVOIDQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [ITEMVOIDAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TICKETRETQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TICKETRETAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [ITEMRETQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [ITEMRETAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [ADDLOANTOTQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [ADDLOANTOTAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERCASHQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERCASHAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERATMOFFLINEQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERATMOFFLINEAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERCHRGOFFLINEQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERCHRGOFFLINEAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERCHKQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERCHKAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERBDOREBATESQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERBDOREBATESAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OVERTENDERQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OVERTENDERAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHERTENDERQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHERTENDERAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERCCMQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERCCMAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERARCODQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERARCODAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERADBQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERADBAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERFWV5QTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERFWV5AMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDEREWT1QTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDEREWT1AMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERTOP20KQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERTOP20KAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [CCARDATMCHRGONLINEQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [CCARDATMCHRGONLINEAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHTENDERSMGCQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHTENDERSMGCAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHTENDERSODEXOQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHTENDERSODEXOAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHTENDERCORPACCQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHTENDERCORPACCAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHTENDERDIFFEREDQTY] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [OTHTENDERDIFFEREDAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TENDERTOTAL] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [VATSALEAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [VATSALETAXVALUE] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [VATEXSALEAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [VATEXSALETAXVALUE] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [ZERORATEDSALEAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [ZERORATEDSALETAXVALUE] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TOTALAMT] [nvarchar](300) NULL,
    [TOTALTAXVALUE] [nvarchar](300) NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
INSERT [dbo].[TermZTran] ([HeaderID], [WorkDate], [ProcessDate], [ProcessMode], [POSCount], [SalePharma], [SaleNonPharma], [VoidAmount], [VoidCount], [ZCOUNTER], [STORE], [POS], [DATE], [TIME], [OGTOTAL], [NGTOTAL], [BEGSI], [LASSI], [TSALES], [QTYREGULAR], [SALESREGULAR], [QTYSCD20], [SALESCD20], [QTYSCD5], [SALESCD5], [QTYPWD], [SALEPWD], [QTYTGOVT], [SALESTGOVT], [QTYZERORATED], [SALESZERORATED], [QTYVATEXEMPT], [SALESVATEXEMPT], [TDISCOUNT], [DISCREGULARQTY], [DISCREGULARAMT], [DISCSCD20QTY], [DISCSCD20AMT], [DISCSCD5QTY], [DISCSCD5AMT], [DISCPWD20QTY], [DISCPWD20AMT], [DISCPWD5QTY], [DISCPWD5AMT], [DNETSALES], [DGROSSSALES], [SALESACCOUNTABILITY], [VOIDTRANQTY], [VOIDTRANAMT], [ITEMVOIDQTY], [ITEMVOIDAMT], [TICKETRETQTY], [TICKETRETAMT], [ITEMRETQTY], [ITEMRETAMT], [ADDLOANTOTQTY], [ADDLOANTOTAMT], [TENDERCASHQTY], [TENDERCASHAMT], [TENDERATMOFFLINEQTY], [TENDERATMOFFLINEAMT], [TENDERCHRGOFFLINEQTY], [TENDERCHRGOFFLINEAMT], [TENDERCHKQTY], [TENDERCHKAMT], [TENDERBDOREBATESQTY], [TENDERBDOREBATESAMT], [OVERTENDERQTY], [OVERTENDERAMT], [OTHERTENDERQTY], [OTHERTENDERAMT], [TENDERCCMQTY], [TENDERCCMAMT], [TENDERARCODQTY], [TENDERARCODAMT], [TENDERADBQTY], [TENDERADBAMT], [TENDERFWV5QTY], [TENDERFWV5AMT], [TENDEREWT1QTY], [TENDEREWT1AMT], [TENDERTOP20KQTY], [TENDERTOP20KAMT], [CCARDATMCHRGONLINEQTY], [CCARDATMCHRGONLINEAMT], [OTHTENDERSMGCQTY], [OTHTENDERSMGCAMT], [OTHTENDERSODEXOQTY], [OTHTENDERSODEXOAMT], [OTHTENDERCORPACCQTY], [OTHTENDERCORPACCAMT], [OTHTENDERDIFFEREDQTY], [OTHTENDERDIFFEREDAMT], [TENDERTOTAL], [VATSALEAMT], [VATSALETAXVALUE], [VATEXSALEAMT], [VATEXSALETAXVALUE], [ZERORATEDSALEAMT], [ZERORATEDSALETAXVALUE], [TOTALAMT], [TOTALTAXVALUE]) VALUES (N'35a9637c-4342-4cb4-8f10-1c1d52b09cd4', CAST(0xA1A20000 AS SmallDateTime), CAST(0xA1A80478 AS SmallDateTime), N'sqljob', 1, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0, N'0001', N'0040', N'001', N'16/04/2013', N'19:06', N'0.00', N'73420.22', N'0000000001', N'0000000078', N'69827.81', N'75', N'48543.85', N'7', N'15683.96', N'4', N'940.00', N'6', N'4520.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'1', N'140.00', N'8283.98', N'30', N'4361.04', N'7', N'3136.79', N'4', N'41.96', N'3', N'723.21', N'3', N'20.98', N'56502.49', N'73420.22', N'61760.30', N'3', N'5815.95', N'-33', N'-1282.50', N'-14', N'-5886.00', N'-151', N'-3923.18', N'2', N'6000.00', N'68', N'46045.65', N'1', N'67.50', N'3', N'751.75', N'1', N'3200.00', N'2', N'310.82', N'2', N'-3.00', N'3', N'0.03', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'11', N'9096.12', N'5', N'800.00', N'5', N'450.00', N'1', N'1041.43', N'0', N'0.00', N'61760.30', N'43815.32', N'5257.81', N'15823.96', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'59639.28', N'5257.81')
INSERT [dbo].[TermZTran] ([HeaderID], [WorkDate], [ProcessDate], [ProcessMode], [POSCount], [SalePharma], [SaleNonPharma], [VoidAmount], [VoidCount], [ZCOUNTER], [STORE], [POS], [DATE], [TIME], [OGTOTAL], [NGTOTAL], [BEGSI], [LASSI], [TSALES], [QTYREGULAR], [SALESREGULAR], [QTYSCD20], [SALESCD20], [QTYSCD5], [SALESCD5], [QTYPWD], [SALEPWD], [QTYTGOVT], [SALESTGOVT], [QTYZERORATED], [SALESZERORATED], [QTYVATEXEMPT], [SALESVATEXEMPT], [TDISCOUNT], [DISCREGULARQTY], [DISCREGULARAMT], [DISCSCD20QTY], [DISCSCD20AMT], [DISCSCD5QTY], [DISCSCD5AMT], [DISCPWD20QTY], [DISCPWD20AMT], [DISCPWD5QTY], [DISCPWD5AMT], [DNETSALES], [DGROSSSALES], [SALESACCOUNTABILITY], [VOIDTRANQTY], [VOIDTRANAMT], [ITEMVOIDQTY], [ITEMVOIDAMT], [TICKETRETQTY], [TICKETRETAMT], [ITEMRETQTY], [ITEMRETAMT], [ADDLOANTOTQTY], [ADDLOANTOTAMT], [TENDERCASHQTY], [TENDERCASHAMT], [TENDERATMOFFLINEQTY], [TENDERATMOFFLINEAMT], [TENDERCHRGOFFLINEQTY], [TENDERCHRGOFFLINEAMT], [TENDERCHKQTY], [TENDERCHKAMT], [TENDERBDOREBATESQTY], [TENDERBDOREBATESAMT], [OVERTENDERQTY], [OVERTENDERAMT], [OTHERTENDERQTY], [OTHERTENDERAMT], [TENDERCCMQTY], [TENDERCCMAMT], [TENDERARCODQTY], [TENDERARCODAMT], [TENDERADBQTY], [TENDERADBAMT], [TENDERFWV5QTY], [TENDERFWV5AMT], [TENDEREWT1QTY], [TENDEREWT1AMT], [TENDERTOP20KQTY], [TENDERTOP20KAMT], [CCARDATMCHRGONLINEQTY], [CCARDATMCHRGONLINEAMT], [OTHTENDERSMGCQTY], [OTHTENDERSMGCAMT], [OTHTENDERSODEXOQTY], [OTHTENDERSODEXOAMT], [OTHTENDERCORPACCQTY], [OTHTENDERCORPACCAMT], [OTHTENDERDIFFEREDQTY], [OTHTENDERDIFFEREDAMT], [TENDERTOTAL], [VATSALEAMT], [VATSALETAXVALUE], [VATEXSALEAMT], [VATEXSALETAXVALUE], [ZERORATEDSALEAMT], [ZERORATEDSALETAXVALUE], [TOTALAMT], [TOTALTAXVALUE]) VALUES (N'35a9637c-4342-4cb4-8f10-1c1d52b09cd4', CAST(0xA1A20000 AS SmallDateTime), CAST(0xA1A80478 AS SmallDateTime), N'sqljob', 2, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0, N'0001', N'0040', N'002', N'16/04/2013', N'19:06', N'0.00', N'60296.14', N'0000000001', N'0000000076', N'58336.24', N'61', N'44770.01', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'7', N'4597.00', N'15', N'8269.23', N'4', N'700.00', N'3890.95', N'17', N'3890.95', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'49572.91', N'60296.14', N'54445.29', N'2', N'186.00', N'-133', N'-3567.50', N'-7', N'-6661.50', N'-90', N'-2085.50', N'2', N'6000.00', N'66', N'39251.01', N'1', N'67.50', N'1', N'149.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'3', N'-22.68', N'10', N'3989.88', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0', N'11', N'205.23', N'11', N'41.05', N'13', N'41.05', N'8', N'4323.75', N'9', N'2500.00', N'1', N'100.00', N'2', N'3799.50', N'0', N'0.00', N'54445.29', N'40603.68', N'4872.38', N'700.00', N'0.00', N'8269.23', N'0.00', N'49572.91', N'4872.38')
INSERT [dbo].[TermZTran] ([HeaderID], [WorkDate], [ProcessDate], [ProcessMode], [POSCount], [SalePharma], [SaleNonPharma], [VoidAmount], [VoidCount], [ZCOUNTER], [STORE], [POS], [DATE], [TIME], [OGTOTAL], [NGTOTAL], [BEGSI], [LASSI], [TSALES], [QTYREGULAR], [SALESREGULAR], [QTYSCD20], [SALESCD20], [QTYSCD5], [SALESCD5], [QTYPWD], [SALEPWD], [QTYTGOVT], [SALESTGOVT], [QTYZERORATED], [SALESZERORATED], [QTYVATEXEMPT], [SALESVATEXEMPT], [TDISCOUNT], [DISCREGULARQTY], [DISCREGULARAMT], [DISCSCD20QTY], [DISCSCD20AMT], [DISCSCD5QTY], [DISCSCD5AMT], [DISCPWD20QTY], [DISCPWD20AMT], [DISCPWD5QTY], [DISCPWD5AMT], [DNETSALES], [DGROSSSALES], [SALESACCOUNTABILITY], [VOIDTRANQTY], [VOIDTRANAMT], [ITEMVOIDQTY], [ITEMVOIDAMT], [TICKETRETQTY], [TICKETRETAMT], [ITEMRETQTY], [ITEMRETAMT], [ADDLOANTOTQTY], [ADDLOANTOTAMT], [TENDERCASHQTY], [TENDERCASHAMT], [TENDERATMOFFLINEQTY], [TENDERATMOFFLINEAMT], [TENDERCHRGOFFLINEQTY], [TENDERCHRGOFFLINEAMT], [TENDERCHKQTY], [TENDERCHKAMT], [TENDERBDOREBATESQTY], [TENDERBDOREBATESAMT], [OVERTENDERQTY], [OVERTENDERAMT], [OTHERTENDERQTY], [OTHERTENDERAMT], [TENDERCCMQTY], [TENDERCCMAMT], [TENDERARCODQTY], [TENDERARCODAMT], [TENDERADBQTY], [TENDERADBAMT], [TENDERFWV5QTY], [TENDERFWV5AMT], [TENDEREWT1QTY], [TENDEREWT1AMT], [TENDERTOP20KQTY], [TENDERTOP20KAMT], [CCARDATMCHRGONLINEQTY], [CCARDATMCHRGONLINEAMT], [OTHTENDERSMGCQTY], [OTHTENDERSMGCAMT], [OTHTENDERSODEXOQTY], [OTHTENDERSODEXOAMT], [OTHTENDERCORPACCQTY], [OTHTENDERCORPACCAMT], [OTHTENDERDIFFEREDQTY], [OTHTENDERDIFFEREDAMT], [TENDERTOTAL], [VATSALEAMT], [VATSALETAXVALUE], [VATEXSALEAMT], [VATEXSALETAXVALUE], [ZERORATEDSALEAMT], [ZERORATEDSALETAXVALUE], [TOTALAMT], [TOTALTAXVALUE]) VALUES (N'35a9637c-4342-4cb4-8f10-1c1d52b09cd4', CAST(0xA1A20000 AS SmallDateTime), CAST(0xA1A80478 AS SmallDateTime), N'sqljob', 3, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0.0000, 0, N'0001', N'0040', N'003', N'16/04/2013', N'19:06', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0000000000', N'0000000000', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'1', N'0.01', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00', N'0.00')
```

Please help...

Comment: If you want your final result to be on a single row, you shouldn't be grouping at all (in the outer query), just aggregating - `group by` returns a single row for each unique combination of *all* the values in *all* the columns included in the `group by` clause.

Comment: Can you explain what this query is supposed to do (beyond returning output on a single line)?

Comment: But if I removed the OUTER GROUP BY, I always get this error message '''Column 'dt.BR_CODE' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause'''

Comment: I suppose, when you do aggregate, you need to GROUP,

Comment: If you include aggregate columns without an explicit `group by`, the results will be aggregated across the entire dataset - this is equivalent to `group by ()`.

Comment: Hmm.. I think I was too much GROUP'ing things, anyway, just to clarify my understanding of the GROUP, I should only GROUP those that aren't part of the AGGREGATE meaning if (x + y) as sum is part of the query, it shouldn't be part of the GROUP BY clause (the sum)?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28896/discussion-between-mark-bannister-and-paul-polo)

Answer (score 0):

You have quite weird data schema. Did you try to store numeric values as decimal rather than as nvarchar. Possible this may should help -

```
SELECT BR_CODE
    ,N_CHECK
    ,CLAS_C
    ,CLAS_TRD_C
    ,STOR_NO
    ,SUM(TSL_NEW_A) AS TSL_NEW_A
    ,SUM(TSL_OLD_A) AS TSL_OLD_A
    ,SalesType
    ,SUM(TSL_DAY_A) AS TSL_DAY_A
    ,SUM(TSL_DIS_A) AS TSL_DIS_A
    ,TSL_DIS_B = 0
    ,SUM(TSL_DIS_C) AS TSL_DIS_C
    ,TSL_DIS_D = 0
    ,SUM(TSL_DIS_E) AS TSL_DIS_E
    ,TSL_Dis_F = 0
    ,TSL_Dis_G = 0
    ,TSL_Dis_H = 0
    ,TSL_Dis_I = 0
    ,TSL_Dis_J = 0
    ,TSL_Dis_K = 0
    ,TSL_Dis_L = 0
    ,SUM(TSL_TAX_A) AS TSL_TAX_A
    ,TSL_TAX_B = 0
    ,TSL_ADJ_A = 0
    ,TSL_ADJ_POS = 0
    ,TS_ADJ_NEG = 0
    ,TSL_ADJ_NT_POS = 0
    ,TSL_ADJ_NT_NEG = 0
    ,SUM(TSL_NET_A) AS TSL_NET_A
    ,SUM(TSL_VOID) AS TSL_VOID
    ,SUM(TSL_RFND) AS TSL_RFND
    ,SUM(TSL_TX_SAL) AS TSL_TX_SAL
    ,SUM(TSL_NX_SAL) AS TSL_NX_SAL
    ,TSL_CHG
    ,SUM(TSL_CSH) AS TSL_CSH
    ,SUM(TSL_GC) AS TSL_GC
    ,TSL_EPS = 0
    ,TSL_TND = 0
    ,TSL_MCRD = 0
    ,TSL_VISA = 0
    ,TSL_AMEX = 0
    ,TSL_DINERS = 0
    ,TSL_JBC = 0
    ,TSL_OTCRD = 0
    ,TSL_SV_CHG = 0
    ,TSL_OT_CHG = 0
    ,SUM(TSL_FT) AS TSL_FT
    ,SUM(TSL_LT) AS TSL_LT
    ,SUM(TSL_NT) AS TSL_NT
    ,SUM(TSL_BEG_INV) AS TSL_BEG_INV
    ,SUM(TSL_END_INV) AS TSL_END_INV
    ,SUM(TSL_TC_CASH) AS TSL_TC_CASH
    ,SUM(TSL_TC_GC) AS TSL_TC_GC
    ,TSL_TC_EPS = 0
    ,TSL_TC_TND = 0
    ,TSL_TC_MCD = 0
    ,TSL_TC_VIS = 0
    ,TSL_TC_AMX = 0
    ,TSL_TC_DIN = 0
    ,TSL_TC_JBC = 0
    ,TSL_TC_OC = 0
    ,TSL_MCH = 0
    ,TSL_SRL = 0
    ,SUM(TSL_ZCNT) AS TSL_ZCNT
    ,TSL_TIME
    ,TSL_DTE
FROM(
    SELECT
          BR_CODE
        , N_CHECK
        , CLAS_C
        , CLAS_TRD_C
        , STOR_NO
        , SUM(TSL_NEW_A) AS TSL_NEW_A
        , SUM(TSL_OLD_A) AS TSL_OLD_A
        , SalesType
        , SUM(TSL_DAY_A) AS TSL_DAY_A
        , SUM(TSL_DIS_A) AS TSL_DIS_A
        , SUM(TSL_DIS_C) AS TSL_DIS_C
        , SUM(TSL_DIS_E) AS TSL_DIS_E
        , SUM(TSL_TAX_A) AS TSL_TAX_A
        , SUM(TSL_NET_A) AS TSL_NET_A
        , SUM(TSL_VOID) AS TSL_VOID
        , SUM(TSL_RFND) AS TSL_RFND
        , SUM(TSL_TX_SAL) AS TSL_TX_SAL
        , SUM(TSL_NX_SAL) AS TSL_NX_SAL
        , TSL_CHG
        , SUM(TSL_CSH) AS TSL_CSH
        , SUM(TSL_GC) AS TSL_GC
        , SUM(TSL_FT) AS TSL_FT
        , SUM(TSL_LT) AS TSL_LT
        , SUM(TSL_NT) AS TSL_NT
        , SUM(TSL_BEG_INV) AS TSL_BEG_INV
        , SUM(TSL_END_INV) AS TSL_END_INV
        , SUM(TSL_TC_CASH) AS TSL_TC_CASH
        , SUM(TSL_TC_GC) AS TSL_TC_GC
        , SUM(TSL_ZCNT) AS TSL_ZCNT
        , TSL_TIME
        , TSL_DTE
    FROM (
        SELECT 
              BR_CODE = 0
            , N_CHECK = 0
            , CLAS_C = 0
            , CLAS_TRD_C = 0
            , STOR_NO = 0
            , TSL_NEW_A = SUM(CAST(NGTOTAL AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(OGTOTAL AS DECIMAL(16,2))) 
            , TSL_OLD_A = SUM(CAST(OGTOTAL AS DECIMAL(16,2))) 
            , SalesType = 0
            , SUM(((CAST(SALESREGULAR AS DECIMAL(16,2)) - CAST(SALESVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) +
                CAST(SALESCD20 AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALESCD5 AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALEPWD AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALESTGOVT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + 
                CAST(SALESZERORATED AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCREGULARAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCSCD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCSCD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCPWD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCPWD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(VOIDTRANAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(ITEMVOIDAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(TICKETRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(ITEMRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)))/1.12) + CAST(SALESVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) AS TSL_DAY_A --SUM(cast(round((cast(TSALES as decimal)/1.12),2) AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_DAY_A --Help
            ,SUM(ABS(CAST(DISCREGULARAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)))) AS TSL_DIS_A
            ,SUM(CAST(DISCSCD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(DISCSCD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_DIS_C
            ,SUM(CAST(DISCSCD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(DISCSCD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_DIS_E
            ,SUM(CAST(VATSALEAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_TAX_A
            ,SUM(CAST(DGROSSSALES AS DECIMAL(16,2)) - CAST(TOTALTAXVALUE AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_NET_A --Help
            ,SUM(CAST(VOIDTRANAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_VOID
            ,SUM(ABS(CAST(ITEMRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)))) AS TSL_RFND
            ,SUM(((CAST(SALESREGULAR AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(SALESVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) +
                CAST(SALESCD20 AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALESCD5 AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALEPWD AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(SALESTGOVT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + 
                CAST(SALESZERORATED AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCREGULARAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCSCD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCSCD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCPWD20AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(DISCPWD5AMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(VOIDTRANAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(ITEMVOIDAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(TICKETRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) +
                CAST(ITEMRETAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)))) AS TSL_TX_SAL --Help
            ,(CAST(SALESVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + (CAST(ZERORATEDSALEAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) - CAST(ZERORATEDSALETAXVALUE AS DECIMAL(16,2)))) AS TSL_NX_SAL
            ,SUM(CAST(CCARDATMCHRGONLINEAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_CHG --Help
            ,SUM(CAST(TENDERCASHAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_CSH
            ,SUM(CAST(OTHTENDERSMGCAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2)) + CAST(OTHTENDERSODEXOAMT AS DECIMAL(16,2))) AS TSL_GC --+ CAST(TENDERCHKAMT AS DECIMAL) AS TSL_GC
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(BEGSI) AS INT)) AS TSL_FT
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(LASSI) AS INT)) AS TSL_LT
            ,SUM(CAST((CAST(QTYREGULAR AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYSCD20 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYSCD5 AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYPWD AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYTGOVT AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(QTYZERORATED AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
                + CAST(QTYVATEXEMPT AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(DISCREGULARQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(DISCSCD20QTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(DISCSCD5QTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(DISCPWD20QTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) 
                + CAST(DISCPWD5QTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(VOIDTRANQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2)) + CAST(ITEMVOIDQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2))*-1 + CAST(TICKETRETQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2))*-1 + CAST(ITEMRETQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2))*-1 
                + CAST(ADDLOANTOTQTY AS DECIMAL(18,2))) AS INT)) AS TSL_NT
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(BEGSI) AS INT)) AS TSL_BEG_INV
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(LASSI) AS INT)) AS TSL_END_INV
            ,SUM(CAST(QTYREGULAR AS INT)) as TSL_TC_CASH
            ,SUM(CAST(OTHTENDERSMGCQTY AS INT) + CAST(OTHTENDERSODEXOQTY AS INT)) AS TSL_TC_GC
            ,SUM(CAST(ABS(ZCOUNTER) AS INT)) AS TSL_ZCNT
            ,RIGHT('00'+RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(HH,GETDATE())AS VARCHAR(5))),2)+RIGHT('00'+RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(MI,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(5))),2)+RIGHT('00'+RTRIM(CAST(DATEPART(SS,GETDATE()) AS VARCHAR(5))),2) AS TSL_TIME
            ,SUBSTRING(convert(varchar,WorkDate,111),6,2)+Right(convert(varchar,WorkDate,111),2)+left(convert(varchar,WorkDate,111),4) AS TSL_DTE
        FROM dbo.TermZTran t
        LEFT JOIN (
            SELECT sLessee, sTenantNumber AS TenantCode, sStoreNumber 
            FROM mLandlordStore
        ) tInfo ON t.STORE = tInfo.sStoreNumber
        WHERE CAST(t.Store AS INT) = CAST(@branchcode AS INT) 
            AND tInfo.sLessee = @lesseeCode
            AND CONVERT(nvarchar(10),t.WorkDate,101) = @trandate
            AND CONVERT(nvarchar(10),t.WorkDate,101) = '04/16/2013'
            AND CAST(BR_CODE AS INT) = CAST('0040' AS INT)
        GROUP BY 
              SALESVATEXEMPT
            , ZERORATEDSALEAMT
            , ZERORATEDSALETAXVALUE
            , WorkDate
) tFinal
GROUP BY
        BR_CODE
        ,N_CHECK
        ,CLAS_C
        ,CLAS_TRD_C
        ,STOR_NO
        ,TSL_NEW_A
        ,TSL_OLD_A
        ,SalesType
        ,TSL_DAY_A
        ,TSL_DIS_A
        ,TSL_DIS_C
        ,TSL_DIS_E
        ,TSL_TAX_A
        ,TSL_NET_A
        ,TSL_VOID
        ,TSL_RFND
        ,TSL_TX_SAL
        ,TSL_NX_SAL
        ,TSL_CHG
        ,TSL_CSH
        ,TSL_GC
        ,TSL_FT
        ,TSL_LT
        ,TSL_NT
        ,TSL_BEG_INV
        ,TSL_END_INV
        ,TSL_TC_CASH
        ,TSL_TC_GC
        ,TSL_ZCNT
        ,TSL_TIME
        ,TSL_DTE
) dt
GROUP BY
    dt.BR_CODE
    ,dt.CLAS_C
    ,dt.CLAS_TRD_C
    ,dt.N_CHECK
    ,dt.STOR_NO
    ,dt.SalesType
    ,TSL_DAY_A
    ,TSL_DIS_A
    ,TSL_DIS_C
    ,TSL_DIS_E
    ,TSL_TAX_A
    ,TSL_NET_A
    ,TSL_VOID
    ,TSL_RFND
    ,TSL_TX_SAL
    ,TSL_NX_SAL
    ,TSL_CHG
    ,TSL_CSH
    ,TSL_GC
    ,TSL_FT
    ,TSL_LT
    ,TSL_NT
    ,TSL_BEG_INV
    ,TSL_END_INV
    ,TSL_TC_CASH
    ,TSL_TC_GC
    ,TSL_ZCNT
    ,TSL_TIME
    ,TSL_DTE
```

Comment: it was a product of bad design habits of a programmer, but we just can't blame these people its already done, and there's a lot of things to change when we want to correct it, too bad, anyway, @Mike was pretty helpful, allowed me to realized my mistake, anyway, thank you for the idea, its a good basis for my next sql script writing.

Comment: its @Mark Bannister, not Mike, my mistake